# Getting an IndexOutOfBounds Exception in my Android App

Tags: java, android, android-studio, game-development

This code tracks what missiles players buy and sets the most recent 3 at the top of the list of missile options for players to easily buy them again. After players purchase missiles, the game crashes, but only if they purchase certain ones or purchase a certain amount.

```
Process: com.apps.fast.counterforcetest, PID: 16063
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 5, Size: 3
    at java.util.LinkedList.checkElementIndex(LinkedList.java:555)
    at java.util.LinkedList.remove(LinkedList.java:525)
    at com.apps.fast.launch.components.ClientDefs.SetMissilePreferred(ClientDefs.java:199)
    at com.apps.fast.launch.launchviews.PurchaseLaunchableView$1$1.onClick(PurchaseLaunchableView.java:198)
```

Here is the code the error points to in CLientDefs.java:199

```
public static void SetMissilePreferred(int lMissile) {
    // Set a purchased missile to go to the top of the preferred list.
    if (MissilePreferences == null)
        MissilePreferences = new LinkedList<>();

    if (MissilePreferences.contains(lMissile))
        MissilePreferences.remove(lMissile); //<---- Line 199

    MissilePreferences.push(lMissile);

    if (MissilePreferences.size() > PREFERENCE_LIST_SIZE)
        MissilePreferences.removeLast();
}
```

`MissilePreferences` is a List of Integers.

Comment: UPDATE: I figured it out. The missile ID being fed into the index is too big for the index.

Comment: Just add this line `MissilePreferences.size();` after this `MissilePreferences.remove(lMissile); ` line. after removing any view from recycler, your adater automatically update list size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a bit of a mixup going on here:

```
if (MissilePreferences.contains(lMissile))
    MissilePreferences.remove(lMissile);
```

`lMissile` is an `int`, right? Representing an ID? So when you call `contains`, you're checking if that ID exists in `MissilePreferences`. You want to know if the `List` contains that `int`.

Here's the method signature for [`contains`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#contains(java.lang.Object)):

```
public boolean contains(Object o)
```

It doesn't take a *primitive* like an `int`, it takes an `Object` - so your `int` is being autoboxed into an `Integer` - which makes sense because a `List` can't contain primitives either, only objects. `MissilePreferences` is a list of `Integer`s.

---

So that's all fine, it converts your `int` to an `Integer` and tells you if it exists in the list of `Integer`s, perfect! But then you call `remove` with that original `int`. And there are two versions of that method that take a parameter:

> `public boolean remove(Object o)`
>
> Removes the first occurrence of the specified element from this list, if it is present.

> `public E remove(int index)`
>
> Removes the element at the specified position in this list.

Those do two very different things. The `Object` version removes the first instance of that object from the list. The `int` version treats the `int` as an *index* and removes whatever is in that position.

When you use `contains`, you're treating your `int` as an element in the list you want to find, and it's automatically converted to an `Integer`. And you want to do the same with `remove` - but there's a different version of that method that takes the `int` you're providing directly. It won't autobox that and call the *other* method, obviously! You'd have to do it yourself:

```
Integer missileId = new Integer(lMissile);
// explicitly passing an Integer object to both - only crucial for #remove
if (MissilePreferences.contains(missileId))
    MissilePreferences.remove(missileId);
```

---

That's what you have to watch out for - outside of arrays and some special classes you might run into elsewhere, collection objects don't contain primitives, so you often want to explicitly work with the `Object` wrapper versions they contain. Especially important for `int`s because of situations like this!

That said, you could just do this:

```
MissilePreferences.remove(new Integer(lMissile));
```

No need to use `contains` - you can just call `remove` and it'll remove the first matching object if it has one. It returns *true* if it removed anything, in case you need to check that

Comment: Dang, that was very informative and I understand exactly what the problem is now. Thank you for the highly detailed and educational answer!

Comment: @user204468 no worries! It's one of those things that can sneak up on ya

Answer (score 0):

Try debugging the code so that you know what are the elements in the list and what element is being removed. I am still confused as to how can you get an index out of bounds exception when you are just accessing the element from the list by its value.